# st_transform not accurately projecting connecting lines of a polygon

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to project rectangular polygons onto a map of North America. My issue stems from the fact that I am specifying the polygon in lat/long, then projecting it. The function `st_transform` is able to accurately transform the points of my polygon, but not the lines connecting those points. How can I get the lines to transform with the whole shape?

This code is a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(world)
proWorld <- st_transform(world, "EPSG:9311")

box <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -110,
                 ymin = 25, 
                 ymax = 33, 
                 xmax = -90), crs = "EPSG:4326") %>%
    st_as_sfc() %>%
    st_transform(crs = st_crs(proWorld))

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = proWorld) +
    geom_sf(data = box, fill = NA) +
    ylim(c(-2182970, 1099711)) +
    xlim(c(-1994737, 2770402))
```

And this is the output I get:
[image: rectangular polygon with non-projected edges]

If this were correct, the resulting red rectangle's edges would curve with the line of latitude

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the rectangle to deform uniformly along its edges you will need to construct the edges from multiple small segments. You could do this in a number of different ways, but one such method uses `stplanr::line_segment`

```r
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(world)
proWorld <- st_transform(world, "EPSG:9311")

box <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -110,
                 ymin = 25, 
                 ymax = 33, 
                 xmax = -90), crs = "EPSG:4326") %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  stplanr::line_segment(n_segments = 100) %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_transform(crs = st_crs(proWorld))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = proWorld) +
  geom_sf(data = box, fill = NA, color = "red", linewidth = 1) +
  ylim(c(-2182970, 1099711)) +
  xlim(c(-1994737, 2770402))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

While agreeing in principle with the accepted answer - the key is segmentation of the polygon - I suggest an alternative approach.

The `stplanr::line_segment()` works only for lines, and introduces a dependency. Equivalent result can be had using `sf::st_segmentize()`; this function would take a polygon for an argument and is a part of "base" {sf}, doing without the {stplanr} dependency - which is a fine but rather specialized package.

```
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(world)
proWorld <- st_transform(world, "EPSG:9311")

box <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -110,
                 ymin = 25, 
                 ymax = 33, 
                 xmax = -90)) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_segmentize(1) %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  st_transform(crs = st_crs(proWorld))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = proWorld) +
  geom_sf(data = box, fill = NA, color = "red", lwd = 2) +
  ylim(c(-2182970, 1099711)) +
  xlim(c(-1994737, 2770402))
```

[image]